# what is equivalent c# code for following statement?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var files = from file in  my.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(CurDir()) orderby file select file;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            orderby file
            select file;
```

**Edit:** use the code from Gabe's answer if you're using .Net 4.0; it's better for the reasons he mentions. Use this if you're using 3.5.

Comment: Hmm, guess i didnt understand the question (an easy mistake, given the vagueness of it).

Answer (score 5):

This is an alternative in newer versions of .Net:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
            orderby file
            select file;
```

Generally speaking, it is preferable to use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` because it does not create a whole array of strings before returning. This not only saves the creation of the array, but allows you to start processing as soon as the first filename is read rather than having to wait until the last one is read.

You can think of `GetFiles()` as `EnumerateFiles().ToArray()`.

Comment: It's similar, but not the same.

Comment: Of course, since you're doing an orderby, it'll have to build a list anyway.

Comment: James Curran: Good point, but `GetFiles()` makes one array, then `OrderBy` *copies* the array and sorts it, returning the new array. If your point was that in either case you have to wait for the enumeration to complete before getting the first element, you're correct. If your point was that `GetFiles` is no less efficient in this case, you're wrong. `var files = Directory.GetFiles(); files.Sort();` would be as efficient.

Answer (score 3):

I'll do it with the *other* syntax :)

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                               .OrderBy(f => f);
```